# Arrays out of bound when trying to empty arraylist in a loop

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a function to calculate the cosine similarity of each 2D matrix row with the first row in the matrix. The cosine similarity of each row will then be added into an arraylist called activation.

Here is the code:

```
 List <Double> probeVectorList = new ArrayList <Double>();
 Double[] probeVectorArr = new Double[countMatrix2[0].length];
 List <Double> contextVectorList = new ArrayList <Double>();
 Double[] contextVectorArr = new Double[countMatrix2[0].length];
 List <Double> activation = new ArrayList <Double>();

 //display matrix
 for (int i = 0; i < countMatrix2.length; i++) {

    System.out.print(arrKeyWords[i]+"   "); //print keywords

    for (int j = 0; j < countMatrix2[0].length; j++) { 

         if (i==0)
         {
             probeVectorList.add(RoundTo2Decimals(contextVector[i][j])); //set the first row as probe vector
             probeVectorArr = probeVectorList.toArray(new Double[0]);
         }

            System.out.print(RoundTo2Decimals(contextVector[i][j])+", "); //print the entire matrix with rounded decimals

            //compute activation
           contextVectorList.add(RoundTo2Decimals(contextVector[i][j])); //here, in every iteration, the rows will be added into the list
           contextVectorArr = contextVectorList.toArray(new Double[0]); //convert list to array

           activation.add(cosineSimilarity(probeVectorArr, contextVectorArr)); //compute cosine similarity between the first row(static) and the subsequent row (cosineSimilarity function will take in 2 vector as input)

             } 

           //array out of bounds exception appears when attempting to calculate cosine similarity whenever I empty the array/list to make way for new rows 
          Arrays.fill(contextVectorArr, null); //empty array to make way for new rows
          contextVectorList.clear(); //empty list to make way for new rows

          System.out.println(" "); 
       }
```

As the comments suggested, whenever I tried to empty the list to make way for the next row, it will display `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` on the line `activation.add(cosineSimilarity(probeVectorArr, contextVectorArr));`. It will work fine if I don't empty it which will then resulted in every row being added into the list. (The matrix contains the same no of column for every row)...

Anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve] - there's a lot of unnecessary code here. I suspect that in doing so, you'll find the problem... and if you don't, it'll make it *much* easier for people to help you, and more useful to later readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting each iteration with an empty list, your `contextVectorList`, and hence the derived `contextVectorArr`, contain **exactly one element** added by the line:

```
contextVectorList.add(RoundTo2Decimals(contextVector[i][j]));
```

Thus, index `1` is, indeed, out of range.